# AES use same IV for encryption and decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm having some issues with my code whereby I am not using the same IV for encryption and decryption. I know in order to do this correctly I have to write the IV to my output file before the data however I am struggling implementing this. Could anyone help me with this issue?

*Edited code code again to show full scope*

```
public class TestFileEncryption {
    private static void mainCrypto(int cipherMode, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws Exception{
        //Let the user enter the key they wish to use
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(UITest.getStoreKey().getBytes(), UITest.getSendAlg()); //Generates a key based on the default keysize for the specified algorithm

        //Generate an Initialization Vector (IV)
        final int ALG_KEYLENGTH = UITest.getStoreKey().length(); //Change this as desired for the security level you want
        byte[] iv = new byte[ALG_KEYLENGTH]; //Save the IV bytes or send it in plaintext with the encrypted data so you can decrypt the data later
        SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom(); //Use SecureRandom to generate random bits. The size of the IV matches the blocksize of the cipher
        prng.nextBytes(iv); //Construct the appropriate IvParameterSpec object for the data to pass to Cipher's init() method

        //Create a Cipher by specifying the following parameters: Alg name, Mode (CBC), Padding (PKC7/PKCS5)
        Cipher cipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance(UITest.getSendAlg() + "/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); // Must specify the mode explicitly as most JCE providers default to ECB mode

        //Initialize the Cipher for Encryption
        cipherForEncryption.init(cipherMode, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        //Declare / Initialize the Data, Convert the Input to Bytes and encrypt or decrypt using doFinal.
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length() - ALG_KEYLENGTH];
        inputStream.read(iv);
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);
        byte[] outputBytes = cipherForEncryption.doFinal(inputBytes);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(iv);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public static void encrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws Exception {
        mainCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile); //ENC_MODE = Constant used to initialize cipher to encryption mode.
    }

    public static void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws Exception {
        mainCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile); //ENC_MODE = Constant used to initialize cipher to encryption mode.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Comment: `byte[] iv = new byte[ALG_KEYLENGTH]` is wrong, because the IV needs to have the same size as the block and not the key. For AES-CBC this is *always* 16 bytes.

Comment: @ArtjomB. accidently key length 128 bit is 16 bytes, but it is more accident that he made it working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just extending answer of @Javier.

it looks like you'd like to use the same method for encryption and decrpytion (depending on the mode) however there's a difference in handling the IV.

You generated a random IV, then you overwrote it with the input of the (plain) input and at the end you wrote it to the output (regardless it's decryption).

So you have to distinguish if the mode is

- encryption - the IV is generated and written to the output before ciphertext
- decryption - the IV is read from the input and used for decryption, but not written to the output

something like that:

```
private void encrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile)  {
    //Declare / Initialize the Data, Convert the Input to Bytes and encrypt or decrypt using doFinal.
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
    byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // 16 for AES-CBC
    SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom(); //Use SecureRandom to generate random bits. The size of the IV matches the blocksize of the cipher
    prng.nextBytes(iv); //Construct the appropriate IvParameterSpec object for the data to pass to Cipher's init() method

    //Create a Cipher by specifying the following parameters: Alg name, Mode (CBC), Padding (PKC7/PKCS5)
    Cipher cipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance(UITest.getSendAlg() + "/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); // Must specify the mode explicitly as most JCE providers default to ECB mode

    //Initialize the Cipher for Encryption
    cipherForEncryption.init(cipherMode, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));      
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);
        byte[] outputBytes = cipherForEncryption.doFinal(inputBytes);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(iv);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}

private void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
    //Declare / Initialize the Data, Convert the Input to Bytes and encrypt or decrypt using doFinal.
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()-16];
    byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // 16 for AES-CBC

    //Create a Cipher by specifying the following parameters: Alg name, Mode (CBC), Padding (PKC7/PKCS5)
    Cipher cipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance(UITest.getSendAlg() + "/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); // Must specify the mode explicitly as most JCE providers default to ECB mode

    //Initialize the Cipher for Encryption
    cipherForEncryption.init(cipherMode, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));      
    inputStream.read(iv);
    inputStream.read(inputBytes);
    byte[] outputBytes = cipherForEncryption.doFinal(inputBytes);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    outputStream.write(outputBytes);
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

To leave out some detail, maybe you could directly use Java CipherOutputStream and CiptherInputStream and the implementation will handle these details for you (if you don't care about exact format).

Next what are you missing is an authentication tag, at least hash of the plaintext assuring integrity of the ciphertext. (it's called authenticated encryption)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how I should fix my issue, if I edit my code above to show the whole program could you please assist me with these fixes? I have two methods for encryption and decryption and I am not sure if they need to be altered.

Comment: you should understand how it has to work (even  without code, on paper), nobody will code in place of you. Simple **if** will do. maybe you could separate the encryption and decryption methods

Comment: that's not what I am looking for. I meant I am unsure if i should split up the input/output streams into two sections. As in should they be in the enc and dec functions as opposed to the mainCrypto function?

Comment: @dny updated with some code. in the mainCrypto you can say *if mode==enrypt, call encrypt() else decrypt(); *  problem with a single method (mainCrypto ) is that you're doing two things (enc and dec) so you have to separate it. And indeed, the cipther text should not be only the "cipther", it will contain IV (and it should contain hash as well)

Comment: @dny and the code is still not foolproof, when calling readBytes in the code it is assume all the array is read. That may be not true, the real code should check it.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I was not aware that I could not use the same input and output streams for encryption and decryption.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion above however I think my IV is still different for enc and dec as the first 32 bytes of my decrypted file are ",IñžhìOS;ãÄvžCthis is a test"

Comment: @dyn you may not use THE SAME method to encrypt and decrypt (mainCrypto) as the operations are NOT SYMMETRIC. please really read your code line by line and understand it. When decrypting, you are writing IV to the decrypted file (wrong), and when encrypting, you are reading IV from the input (instead using the random value). Though I must say good work with hard trying. Crypto is hard to do it properly

Comment: got it working by splitting it into 2 methods and reading the iv bytes before declaring the new IvParameterSpec, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You just have to write the IV before the ciphertext:

```
outputStream.write(iv);
outputStream.write(outputBytes);
```

Then, when decrypting, read the IV and the ciphertext:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[ALG_BLOCKSIZE];
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length() - ALG_BLOCKSIZE];
inputStream.read(iv);
inputStream.read(inputBytes);
```

Here `ALG_BLOCKSIZE` needs to be 16 for AES-CBC.

Comment: I have tried this and now I am getting a BadPaddingException - "Given final block not properly padded"

Comment: Ok so this is kind of working, except now my file is not being properly decrypted in a different location. 

Output before - "#Ð­P¦ºõk
°ò¸this is a test
this is a test
this is a test"

Output now - "this is a test
#Ð­P¦ºõk
°ò¸this is a test"

Comment: have edited my code to suit your suggestion, is it correct?

Comment: @dny It's almost there. When you read the file for decryption, the first `ALG_KEYLENGTH` bytes are the IV (according to the implementation I gave in my answer, you could also have stored the IV somewhere else...) When you read the file for encryption, there is no IV and all the input data has to be encrypted.